# HTML to Excel export using phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

By using PhpSpreadsheet, it will export the html data to xlsx format. But it cannot add data to a specific worksheet in the excel sheet. How the data write to a specific worksheet? I have to write htmlstring1 to worksheet 1 and htmlstring2 to worksheet 2.

Here is the code

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


$htmlString1 = '<table>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Hello World</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Hello World</td>
                  </tr>

              </table>';


$htmlString2 = '<table>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hello User</td>
                      </tr>

                  </table>';

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($htmlString);


$myWorkSheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'My Data');

// Attach the "My Data" worksheet as the first worksheet in the Spreadsheet object
$spreadsheet->addSheet($myWorkSheet, 1);
//$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('My Data');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"');
    $writer->save("php://output");
```